# The progress bar cannot be displayed

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, progress-bar

I am working with Android Studio and I am trying to create a loading dialog. The problem arises when I take the progress bar from the widgets and put it in XML. 
Nothing is displayed...

I attach the part of the code that is for visualization.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:progressTint="@color/CobaltBlue"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tx_loading"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:text="Loading . . . "
    android:textColor="@color/Black"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBar" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is what it produces:

[[image]]

but I expect to get this result

[[image]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this piece of xml. The  `android:indeterminateTint` is missing attribute.

```
<ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/pb_FilterStopsFromListActivity"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:indeterminate="true"
                android:indeterminateTint="@color/black" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have copied your code and tried and it worked normal for me. Can you explain in detail so that i can look into it?

Comment: What I have attached above is all my code.
In practice, I want to create a data loading dialog and I wanted to add a progress bar that turned until I told him to stop. But the progress bar isn't even displayed and I don't understand why. It looks like I'm missing some android tools.